# Sending images from Android to salesforce server

Tags: android, salesforce

I am developing an android application where I need to capture an image and send to the Salesforce server.

Currently I have tried to encode the image to base64 and then send, but I need to send >= 500 images to encode in base64 at the same time.

If I send >=500 images will the server payload accept? and is there any other best way to achieve this?

Comment: @Daniel: easy. it's just 1 answer not accepted in his case :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, can u please answer my question.

Comment: you want to send 500 images in one go? is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Salesforce soap api, which'll be the best way to bulk create data has a limit of 200 rows per request, and a limit of 50Mb total request size per request. You'll need to chunk up your 500 images into multiple calls to [create](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm) so that each individual request doesn't go over these limits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apart from sending the image content in the request, is any way?

Comment: you want to send the images without sending them? i don't understand what you're asking.